# PHP Sending 2 variables onClick to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to send 2 variables (im using php to create an html element)  and when the user clicks, an alert pops up with the 2 variables.
I've set this up:

PHP:

```
$item = array ( 
        'string' => $node->getElementsByTagName('string1')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'string2' => $node->getElementsByTagName('string2')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );


$string1 = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $item['string']);
$string2 = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $item['string2']);

<a href="#" onclick="doSomething($string1, $string2)" id="'.$title.'" return false;"  title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function doSomething(variable1,variable2) {

    var myVar1 = variable1;
    var myVar2 = variable2;

        alert (myVar1+ ' ' +myVar2);
        return false;

    }
</script>
```

I tried this but when I click the link nothing happens.

What is the proper way to send variables from php to javascript?

Thank you for your time.
Is it possible to do this?

```
  <a href="#" onclick"doSomething(this) id="'.string1.'" description="'.string2.'" />link </a>
```

And do this instead of the other solution?

```
<script>
        function doSomething(obj) {

    if(obj!= null)
 alert ('Obj is Null');
 }else {
            alert (obj.getAttributeById("id")+' '+obj.getAttributeById("description"));
            return false;

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: What error do you get in JavaScript?

Comment: Strings in Javascript must be quoted. You're substituting the literal value, not passing a variable.

Comment: And it looks like your HTML is invalid..

Comment: @putvande JS:The alert isn't appearing. and what part is invalid if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: You have a `return false"` in your `a` tag where you can't have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't quote the parameters in your onclick, so your code looks literally like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSomething(Hello, World!)" ...
```

turning your variables' contents into undefined variables and a syntax error ("Not bracket"?).

Try

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSomething('$title', '$string')" id= etc...
```

instead.. Note the quotes around the variables. Also note that you should NEVER directly dump PHP data into a Javascript context like this. As you've found out, the slightest glitch and you've introduced a JS syntax error, which kills the ENTIRE javascript block.

Always output json_encode()'d data, ensuring that you're generating syntactically valid JS code.

Comment: What would you recommend instead of directly dumping PHP data into javascript? BTW thank you for your answer! Im about to try it!

Answer (score -1):

You just need to concat the values into your echo string:

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick="doSomething(\'' . $title . '\', \'' . $string . '\')" id="' . $title . '" return false;"  title="' . $title . '">' . $title . '</a></strong><br />';
```

Answer (score -1):

When you are printing the php variables it prints only the variable, so if $title equals Hello the Java Script interpreter think there a variable in Java Script named Hello.
To avoid this you have to print into the HTML the variable value inside quotes.

```
$string = 'World!';
$title = 'Hello';

echo '<a href="#" onclick="doSomething(\'' . $title . '\', \'' . $string '\')" id="'.$title.'" return false;" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
```